# Proving $ab(a+b)+ac(a+c)+bc(b+c)$ is even

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Prove that $\forall a,b,c\in \mathbb N: ab(a+b)+ac(a+c)+bc(b+c)$ is even

I tried to simplify the expression to something that would always yield an even number: $ (a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)-3abc$ but that's just a sum of numbers that are divisible by $3$...

Is there a way to do this *without checking every combination of the parity of $a,b,c$*?

Comment: Each of $ab(a+b)$, $ac(a+c)$ and $bc(b+c)$ is even. :)

Comment: @darijgrinberg How do you see that without checking the parity of each of them?

Comment: @GitGud Well, you can check that $ab(a+b) + ac(a+c) + bc(b+c)$ is even without checking the parity of each of $a,b,c$, since you can prove the statement $$\forall m,n\in\mathbb N: mn(m+n)\text{ is even},$$ and this statement can be proven by only checking the parity of two numbers.

Comment: @5xum But you need to apply the result to the pairs all the three pairs, so that doesn't avoid the issue.

Comment: @GitGud Yes it does. You use the result to prove that $x=ab(a+b)$ is even. Then you use the result to prove that $y=ac(a+c)$ is even. Then you use the result to prove that $z=bc(b+c)$ is even. (note, you are not "checking parity" when you are only using an already proven statement). Then, since $x,y,z$ are even, so is their sum.

Comment: @5xum But the proof of the result lies on checking the parity of the input of the theorem. To me this doesn't satisfy the requirement of avoiding it.

Comment: @GitGud No, you do not "check the parity of the input of the theorem". You just use the theorem. You cannot possibly be saying that using the theorem does not simplify the parity checking in comparison with the basic method (taking $8$ different parity combinations).

Comment: Now that's some hairsplitting. To me checking the parity of $m$ and $n$ in "$mn(m+n)$ is even" is perfectly fine but checking that of $a,b,c$ in the original statement is mildly annoying, so reducing to two variables is definitely progress. But if you don't like it, Fermat's little theorem yields $m^2 \equiv m \mod 2$ and $n^2 \equiv n \mod 2$, and from here you can complete it yourself.

Comment: @5xum No, I'm not saying that. I said that using the theorem requires to check the parity of $a$ and $b$ (for the first term), check the parity of $a$ and $c$ (for the second term) and check the parity of $b$ and $c$ (for the last term). This I stand by. On the other hand, the OP did say he just wanted to avoid checking all possible combinations, so this is good enough. **Edit:** And yes, you do check the parity of the input of the theorem, by using it, you're implicitly using its proof and thus also the parity checking.

Comment: @GitGud Just out of curiosity, what kind of a proof would, by this strict definition, *avoid* parity checking? The OP probably wanted to know of a way in which he did not have to check all parities by hand, but that obviously is not what you have in mind...

Comment: @5xum I don't know of a proof, I didn't have anything in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below we *derive* that it is *equivalent* to $\, a(a\!+\!1)\,$ is even.

**Lemma** $\,\ ab(a\!+\!b)+ac(a\!+\!c)+bc(b\!+\!c)$ even $\,\iff ab(a\!+\!b)\,$ even

**Proof** $\ \ (\Rightarrow)\ \ $ Let $\,c = 0.\quad (\Leftarrow)\ \ $ Permute $\,a,b,c\,$ and add.

**Lemma** $\,\ ab(a\!+\!b)\,$ even $\iff \color{#c00}{a(a\!+\!1})\,$ even

**Proof**  $\ \ (\Rightarrow)\ \ $ Let $\,b = 1.\quad (\Leftarrow)\ \ \  \color{#c00}a\color{#0a0}b(a\!+\!b)\, =\, \color{#c00}a\,\color{#0a0}b\,(\color{#c00}{a\!+\!1}\, + \,\color{#0a0}{b\!+\!1}\, -\, 2)$

Comment: The side by side proof is a bit confusing but it's nice. I don't understand the last $\Leftarrow$ though you don't assume $a(a+1)$ there.

Comment: @kuhaku Expand $\ \color{#c00}a\,\color{#0a0}b\,(\color{#c00}{a\!+\!1}\, + \,\color{#0a0}{b\!+\!1}\, -\, 2) = b\color{#c00}{a(a\!+\!1)} + a\color{#0a0}{b(b\!+\!1)} -2ab.\,$ Colored terms are even by hypothesis, therefore the sum is even. What is confusing? The point is to show that simple specializations reduce it to an equivalent well-known result. The same idea proves useful in analogous problems (which may be more complex, so not amenable to other brute force approaches).

Answer (score 4):

We will use that for any $A$ the numbers $A$, $3A$ and $A^3$ all have the same parity. Then writing $S$ for our expression, we see
$$\begin{align*}
S &= ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ca(c+a) \\ &\equiv 3ab(a+b) + 3bc(b+c)+3ca(c+a) \\
 &= (a+b)^3 - a^3 - b^3 + (b+c)^3 - b^3 - c^3 + (c+a)^3 - c^3 - a^3 \\
 &\equiv (a+b)^3 + (b+c)^3 + (c+a)^3 \\
 &\equiv (a+b) + (b+c) + (c+a) \equiv 0.
\end{align*}
$$
Here $\equiv$ denotes equality modulo $2$, i.e. $M \equiv N$ means that $M$ and $N$ have the same parity. So $S$ has the same parity as $0$, hence it is always even.

Answer (score 3):

$a$ and $a^2$ are either both even or both odd. So you don't change parity when you replace $a^2$ with $a$:
$$\begin{align}
ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ca(c+a)
&=a^2b+ab^2+b^2c+bc^2+ac^2+a^2c\\
&\equiv ab+ab+bc+bc+ac+ac\\
&= 2(ab+bc+ac)\\
\end{align}$$
which is even.